# How to organize spaces within Confluence (wiki)?

Tags: wiki, spaces, confluence

My company will be using Confluence to store and share our knowledge base on our IT systems, and could be used to cover topics from hardware administration to issues faced by programmers.

I am curious about the best practice for setting up the global spaces. Is it better to have one large, catch-all space for the entire IT department or should the information be broken into multiple spaces focused on a particular domain?

My concern is that breaking the information into several, smaller spaces will hinder the ability to link between related topics that might be categorized into different spaces. For example, we could have 2 spaces to cover our website and our main internal system.  However, there is plenty of overlap between the website apps and the main internal system.

Any advice that can be provided would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'd think this isn't exactly about coding, is it?

Comment: I wasn't sure where to post this. We are mostly using Confluence to share our programming knowledge on a very complex system. I am hoping to learn what others have done to avoid the silly pitfalls.

Comment: with luck *this* will soon be the place: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13716/wikispeedia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have a space for documenting our systems, policies, applications and frameworks in general, one for blogs (where employees write about technical interesting stuff) and one per project. The per project spaces are very small and very project specific. Often a topic of a project makes it into the blog (with the include tag) and from there in a more general way into the general space. Knowledge is moving. You just can't categorize it very strict.